# Configure gitlab omnibus with HTTPS without certificate for nginx on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, https, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having trouble configuring my gitlab server. I want it's external URL to be in **HTTPS**, but I want nginx to work like if it was configured for **HTTP**.

My Gitlab server is installed on an AWS EC2, with an ELB (load balancer) behind. The ELB handle the HTTPS stuff (with and ACM) so the gitlab instance serve on HTTP:

> WEB =>(HTTPS)=> [ELB] =>(HTTP)=> [EC2]

For now, gitlab is configure with `external_url 'http://gitlab.*****'`, it works for basic thing, but for the CI output trace for example, gitlab try to fetch it using an HTTP url, having then the error :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gitlab.*****/[owner]/[project]/-/jobs/44' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://gitlab.*****/[owner]/[project]/-/jobs/44/-/jobs/44/trace.json?state='. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Any idea how I can configure this?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was a combination of both ACM, ELB, a GitLab Docker container (But installed on-EC2 instance shouldn't matter) and this article here:

https://codyparker.com/force-entire-site-ssl-nginx-behind-aws-load-balancer/

which gave me the hints I needed. What I had to do was:

1. Create my Route 53 DNS name
2. Create my ACM Cert based on my new dns name
3. Create my Application ELB with my GitLab EC2 instance with target group being the EC2 instance with port 80.
4. Noting gitlab's documentation on forwarding SSL ports: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#supporting-proxied-ssl
5. Within my gitlab docker container (omnibus gitlab) adding:

```
environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url "https://example.com"
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
        nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
          "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
          "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
        }
```

Which for a physical instance the gitlab.rb should be where you put that. Then not only did I get it working but could automatically redirect mydomain.com in a web browser to https://example.com. Hopefully this helps you and others. Let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT: Target group has to be 80, not 443 like I incorrectly stated. This is because gitlab wouldn't be able to forward SSL if you're passing traffic to it on port 443.